# Is there a way to add new rows to a dataset based on existing row values?

Tags: python, pandas

| State | Manufacturer | Category | Sales $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | AB | Y | 100 |
| TX | AB | Y | 50 |
| Total US | AB | Y | 200 |
| CA | CD | Z | 30 |
| TX | CD | Z | 60 |
| Total US | CD | Z | 100 |

I'm working with a dataset that looks like the above: I have state-level data for most states and a Total US-level row. Because I'm missing some states, I'm trying to create add new rows to my dataset for each Manufacturer-Category combination where the State = "All Other States". and the Sales $ column is the difference between Total US and the sum of the sales for the states I do have. Please see below the endpoint I'm trying to achieve:

| State | Manufacturer | Category | Sales $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | AB | Y | 100 |
| TX | AB | Y | 50 |
| Total US | AB | Y | 200 |
| All Other States | AB | Y | 50 |
| CA | CD | Z | 30 |
| TX | CD | Z | 60 |
| Total US | CD | Z | 100 |
| All Other States | CD | Z | 10 |

Is something like this possible/any ideas on how to achieve this in Python/with Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with a combination of subsetting and `.groupby`. If you are unfamiliar with these operations in pandas you should work through some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. The data is sorted to make sure that "All Other States" comes last. After that, it is grouped and the value in the "All Other States" is subtracted from the total, and then added to the original `df`

```
c = ['Manufacturer','Category']

df = df.sort_values('State',key = lambda x: x.eq('Total US'))

df2 = df.groupby(c)['Sales $'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] * 2 - x.sum()).reset_index()

df = pd.concat([df,df2],ignore_index=True).fillna({'State':'All Other States'}).sort_values(c)
```

or

```
df2 = (df['Sales $'].where(
    df['State'].eq('Total US'),df['Sales $'].mul(-1))
    .groupby([df['Manufacturer'],df['Category']])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    .assign(State = 'All Other'))

(pd.concat([df,df2]).sort_values('Category'))
```

Output:

```
              State Manufacturer Category  Sales $
0                CA           AB        Y      100
1                TX           AB        Y       50
4          Total US           AB        Y      200
6  All Other States           AB        Y       50
2                CA           CD        Z       30
3                TX           CD        Z       60
5          Total US           CD        Z      100
7  All Other States           CD        Z       10
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution! I have a follow-up question: If we complicate it by having more than one column where we need to calculate a value for the 'All Other States' rows (say 'Sales $' and 'Units Sold'), is that possible with this approach?

Comment: in the third line where we have `df.groupby(c)['Sales $']`, change it to `df.groupby(c)[['Sales $','Units Sold']]`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using iteration, my solution will be using concat and groupby functions: First I will create a temperory column ('sales2') to store the values in negative number where the 'State'!='Total US'

```
df['Sales2']=np.where(df['State']!='Total US',df['Sales $']*-1,df['Sales $'])
```

Now I will a create a new dataframe called 'Others' where I will use groupby to group Manufacturer and Category and then use sum2 columns to sum the value. Afterwards, I will rename the 'Sales2' column to 'Sales $'

```
Others=df.groupby(['Manufacturer','Category'],as_index=False)[['Sales2']].sum().rename(columns={'Sales2':'Sales $'})
```

Then I will add a new column to 'Other' dataframe:

```
Others['State']= 'All Other States'

df=(

pd.concat([df,Others],axis=0).sort_values
(['Manufacturer','Category']).reset_index(drop=True).
drop(columns='Sales2')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'State' : ["CA", "TX", "Total US", "CA", "TX", "Total US"],
                   'Manufacturer' : ["AB", "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "CD"],
                   'Category' : ["Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"],
                   'Sales $' : [100, 50, 200, 30, 60, 100]
                   })

r = (df.groupby(['Manufacturer', 'Category'])
       .apply(lambda g: g[g['State'].eq("Total US")].loc[:, 'Sales $']
                .sub( g[g['State'].ne("Total US")].loc[:, 'Sales $'].sum() ))
      ).reset_index(level=[0,1])

r['State'] = 'All Other States'

df = (df.merge(r, how='outer')
        .sort_values(['Manufacturer', 'State'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        )

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
              State Manufacturer Category  Sales $
0  All Other States           AB        Y       50
1                CA           AB        Y      100
2                TX           AB        Y       50
3          Total US           AB        Y      200
4  All Other States           CD        Z       10
5                CA           CD        Z       30
6                TX           CD        Z       60
7          Total US           CD        Z      100
```

**Comment**

if you want to make a calculation for an additional column, parameters to change :

`.loc[:, 'Sales $']` replaced by `.loc[:, ['Sales $', 'Units sold']]`